# Browser loading content from Twitter in admin area?

Tags: dashboard, twitter

I have noticed that when I am in my Dashboard and switching from main Dashboard to for example plugins, Twitter seems to be loading something.

As I am located in China where Twitter is blocked, it always takes forever for my browser to realise that Twitter cannot be loaded, and thus before the page(s) finish loading.

This screenshot is for going to the plugins page, but it happens everywhere in the Dashboard.

[image: Browser at plugin page loading something from platform.twitter.com]

Is this normal? And can it be blocked/removed/undone?

Comment: The default dashboard widgets from WordPress doesn't query twitter in any way. This must come from a custom plugin you're using. Maybe you can post a list of all active plugins here?

Comment: I can assure you that it has nothing to do with any of my plugins, but for the sake of this discussion the list of my network activated plugins is: Easy FancyBox, Gravity Forms, Multisite Dashboard Feed Widget, Widget Logic, WordPress Database Backup, all 5 WPML modules, WP Status Dashboard. The plugin that is not network activated, but activated on this site in particular is: WP-PostRatings

Comment: If it isn't a plugin it must be custom code in your theme files. I've just checked a default installation from trunk with a HTTP sniffer: No outgoing request to twitter.

Comment: As a temporary remedy you could setup a host file on your computer with Twitter to 12.0.0.1, at least then it would 404 instantly instead of timeout.

Comment: ok, this might be helpful: it seems to happen only in Network Admin on Multisite, not on the separate sites inside of the Multisite install.
And no, it's not custom theme code.
@Dunhammzzz apart from the fact that I don't understand what you mean, I think that a 404 won't help me as the pages eventually resolve, it just takes forever.

Comment: @Piet: It will help because the Twitter part will fail instantly, so the page will not be slowed down because of it. And I must agree that by default WordPress does not load anything from Twitter, so it must be something else. Some possible causes: plugins, themes, but also maybe user metadata (avatar images?) or even browser add-ins. Have you tried it in a different browser? (Use `@Jan` or `@Roman` when you reply in a comment and we get a notification)

Comment: @Roman: I assume you mean `127.0.0.1`, not `12.0.0.1`, to refer it to your own computer?

Comment: @Jan: You mean `Dunhamzzz` comment. Yes, I think he had a typo. @Piet: Add a host entry for the twitter host to point it to your localhost. E.g. `platform.twitter.com 127.0.0.1`.

Comment: @Jan, oh ok, I thought when you said 404, that I would get a 404 instead. Normally I do admin on FF, just tried Chrome, same thing going on. The users get their images from gravatar, but those images are linked to email addresses, right?
Anyways I have deactivated all plugins and problem remains.
Of course I can always use my VPN, but that is not always fast and if I don't want to visit restricted sites and just work on my own sites than my VPN would be overkill; that is the reason why I wanted to know what causes this problem. But it seems that it is sth very specific and unexplainable...

Comment: @Roman "add a host entry to point to my localhost"? Sorry, but this is abacadabra for me

Comment: @Piet: If you're on Linux/Mac: Edit the file `/etc/hosts` and add a new line. E.g. `127.0.0.1 platform.twitter.com`. If you're on Windows, the file is located under `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\``. You may also need to flush your local dns cache. This is only a quick&dirty fix. Every request which would go to `platform.twitter.com` is redirected to your local system. Therefore, you should try `anu`s suggestions to find out what the real problem is.

Comment: @Piet: The hosts file is a file on your computer where you can specify the IP addresses of specific domains, overriding normal DNS lookups. [This blog post explains how to edit it on a Mac.](http://decoding.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/how-to-edit-the-hosts-file-in-mac-os-x-leopard/) If you add a line with `127.0.0.1 platform.twitter.com`, all requests for that domain will loopback to your own computer, and thus give a quick error instead of a long timeout. You can remove the line later when you no longer need it.

Comment: @Roman @Jan thanks, this works perfect and if I have my VPN on I still can visit Twitter, so I'm covered!
I fully realise that this is not a real solution, but it works for me and I think we have spent enough time on this nuisance... Thanks to you both!

Comment: @Piet: Great that it solves your problem, but we did not really solve the root issue, so this question will hang around as "unanswered". I suggest you delete it yourself, unless you want to dig deeper into it some time later.

Comment: @Jan: well obviously I would like to know a real solution at some point, but I also don't want to waste people's time any further as it is obviously a bigger issue than first assumed. It is also not easy to test it for other people, because those people have to be in countries where Twitter is blocked and there are only a handful of those...
And I don't like to delete my question as I already have bookmarked it for the temporary solution.

Comment: @Jan I voted to close this question as it is too localised. Perhaps you and @Roman @Aun and @Dunhamzzz can vote to close it too? It'll still be here then for reference, so best of both worlds?

Comment: Look at the generated source code in the browser and search for twitter.com to see if you can spot where is being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem not resolved, temporary solution is to add a host entry for the twitter host to point it to localhost as offered by @Dunhamzzz and explained further by @Roman and @Jan

Answer (score 0):

- What happens when you try it with all your plugins disabled?
- What happens when you try is with the default WP theme?
- What happens when you try it with a different browser that has no browser extensions or add-ins installed?
- What happens when you set twitter.com -> 127.0.0.1 as suggested?

Comment: the problem only manifests itself in network admin of a multisite install. 
When all plugins are disabled the same thing happens, haven't tried disabling all themes, because although it is a sandbox site, the main site is stil live. I don't have another browser without any extensions installed and the suggestion twitter -> 127.0.0.1 works brilliant

Answer (score 0):

Piet,

I had the same situation (I am in Beijing) and just now figured out the solution that works for me.

I am using a premium theme from Themolution and they included their own dashboard framework, and found out it includes a direct twitter widget connection linked to follow their twitter acount...

I tried hard coding the dashboard widgets away (also possible via WP Total Hacks plugin), but in the end the Twitter Update widget still stayed available, and it wasnt a plugin I installed, so I checked the html output which indicated that something wanted to follow themolution's twitter.
Inside their "theme-dashboard.php" they link to a twitter plugin they included in their "../themolution/assets/includes/widgets" folder.

I edited the theme-dashboard.php and now everything loads like a charm.
Keep in mind for me it was only loading twitter on the actual dashboard page, NOT on the plugin page and others..

Hope this helps a bit.

cheers
bas